# Module function magic.from_file returns different result in Windows and Centos

Tags: python, windows, centos, mime-types, python-magic

The `from_file` in python package `python-magic` returns different results for the same file in Windows vs Centos.

For e.g on Windows,

```py
from magic import from_file
print(from_file("path\to\file_name.msi", mime=True))

# Below is the output
application/x-msi
```

on Centos

```py
from magic import from_file
print(from_file("path/to/file_name.msi", mime=True))

# Below is the output
application/msword
```